# How to empty socket read/write buffers in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, pthreads

I am working on this distributed computing project and I have to simulate some of the 'nodes' failing for sometime,i.e they won't be able to read or write to any of the outgoing tcp connections.One way to do it would be to read and discard messages but I looking for any inbuilt options in C/C++ wherein you can set the sockets to discard any incoming messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simulate failure by closing sockets you're missing a lot of cases where problems occur. You,  *probably*, want to test both, closed and non-responsive end points. On-host solutions, like closing the socket simulate host errors, but network ones need out of application/os support solutions.

Closed sockets clean themselves up. The OS running with the closed sockets returns an error when you try to access it. All of these things are things you should check for. However, a real failure, particularly in the network as opposed to the host, will just drop packets. This can leave your system waiting, potentially for a long time while tcp times out.

The best way to simulate a network failure is with firewall rules. Block one or both ends of the connection at the firewall, simulating a network failure. iptables, and I'm sure other solutions, allows you to drop some fraction of packets or packets with certain characteristics.

Comment: Although the firewall solution was not the right one for this problem, instead of closing the sockets I just turned those nodes into zombies which responded with failure messages all the time. That sort of took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Just close all the sockets that the "failed" nodes are using.

Depending on how OP node app is done (which is not mentioned in a question).. easiest way to simulate failed node is either 'kill' a node application then all TCP 'close' packets will be skipped and other nodes will be not aware of connection closed OR (as a first stage) just manually close all communication sockets on a node. That means not completely clean experiment because other nodes will be aware of connection closed in 'proper' way but will be sufficient to check how rest of system behave with certain node is lost.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said. Depending on how OP node app is done (which is not mentioned in a question).. easiest way to simulate failed node is either 'kill' a node application then all TCP 'close' packets will be skipped and other nodes will be not aware of connection closed OR (as a first stage) just manually close all communication sockets on a node. That means not completely clean experiment because other nodes will be aware of connection closed in 'proper' way but will be sufficient to check how rest of system behave with certain node is lost.

Comment: I did but problem is that giving a straight complete answer without 'place to think' could lead to heavy brain damage if you know what I mean... I suppose that pointing to right direction is worth much more then a ready made answer without understanding why it should be done like that..

Comment: Sorry, I meant your original post, before [Middaparka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109825/middaparka)'s edit. I couldn't edit it because I didn't understand its meaning. It is now perfectly clear however.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native speaker and a bit tired today, so wrote a really weird thing in the initial post... =)

Comment: No problem. Not being a native speaker too, I couldn't get what apparently was very clear to [Middaparka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109825/middaparka). Hence the question. But it is now perfectly clear for me. thank you (+1).

Comment: I did think of closing the sockets but decided against  it because these nodes that fail will also recover after sometime and if I close the connection at fail I will have to make  new connections later which in the context of the program and with the network available would be very costly.